# Is there a Load Balancer with Direct Server Return (DSR) for Windows

Tags: load-balancing, pen

Is there any load balancer to perform Load Balancing with Direct Server Return (DSR) on Windows.

1. The Pen Load Balancer http://siag.nu/pen/  can perform DSR on Linux and there is  Windows version but there is no description how to perform DSR on windows. 
   The Pen's manual specifies this for Linux: 
   pen -df -O “acl 1 permit 192.168.2.11” -O “tarpit_acl 1” -O “dsr_if eth1” 192.168.2.10:80 192.168.2.2 192.168.2.3 
   However the “-O” option is not available on windows as there is no epoll. Also Widnows don’t use interface names sach as “eth0”. So how to use it on Windows?

If pen can't do this then is there any other way to do DSR on windows? Perhaps  Windows Network Load Balancing ? 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725691.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Pen load balancer does not offer DSR on windows at this time. The only way to accomplish DSR with Pen on windows is to run a Linux virtual machine with Pen load balancer using Hyper-V or virtual box.